# microsoft office 2010 logs - last used date office programs

Tags: windows-7, ms-office

I need to determined whether a user used office in the last 3 months.
Where can i find a log or something that can give me that information in windows 7.
Thanks!

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general operating system tech support.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the last used date of the execuatable file.

It should be in `C:/Program Files/Microsoft Office/` folder. Find the .exe file for the office program you want to check. eg: word, excel, powerpoint.

Right Click and select properties. Under the general tab you will see accessed with a date and time.

You can also do this on the desktop and start menu shortcuts.